# jQuery Validation with fields that are added to the form dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have following form:

```
<form class="form-validation">
  <input name="product[0][name]" id="form_product[0][name]" data-rule-required="true">
</form>
```

which is validated with jQuery validation plugin. I call it like this:

```
$(".form-validation").validate();
```

Validation works as expected. Then I have a button which dynamically adds fields to the form, basically it creates this:

```
<form class="form-validation">
  <input name="product[0][name]" id="form_product[0][name]" data-rule-required="true">
  <input name="product[1][name]" id="form_product[1][name]" data-rule-required="true">
  <input name="product[2][name]" id="form_product[2][name]" data-rule-required="true">
  ...
</form>
```

Now after this validation does not behave OK anymore. It still validates form but I get strange results. Sometimes onsubmit value from filed3 is moved to field2, and rules are passed between fields as well...

I think I would need to tell validator that new fields have been added, but I don't know how?

Comment: Which plugin?  The "jQuery Validation" plugin as mentioned in the question, or the "jQuery Validation Engine" as tagged?  They are two different things.

Comment: Based on the code `.validate()`, I've updated your tags.

Comment: **Quote OP:**  _"I get strange results. Sometimes onsubmit value from filed3 is moved to field2, and rules are passed between fields as well"_ ~ See the second part of my answer below.  You've duplicated the `id` on the second and third field.  `id`'s must be unique or you'll get strange results, just like you described.

Answer (score 4):

To apply rules to dynamically created fields, you would call the [`rules('add')` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules) immediately *after* you create the new input fields.  Since you didn't show any of the code that adds the new fields, I cannot show you an exact demo of this technique.

**HOWEVER, since your rules are already part of the HTML attributes, this demo below shows that your code should already be working fine:**

**http://jsfiddle.net/WVbmj/**

---

Quote OP:

> It still validates form but I get strange results. Sometimes onsubmit
>   value from filed3 is moved to field2, and rules are passed between
>   fields as well.

That's probably because you have a duplicate `id`, `id="form_product[1][name]"`,  on your second & third `input` elements.  `id`'s must be unique or you'll get strange results like this.  Fix this problem like I did in the demo above.

Again, **it's working** when this `id` problem is fixed:  **http://jsfiddle.net/WVbmj/**

Comment: All my rules are defined in HTML trough `data-rule` attributes like you see above in my question. I call validation  `$(".form-validation").validate();`. I have tried calling .rules('add') like you suggested even before I have opened this question but was not workign for me...

Comment: @PrimozRome, please read the rest of my question.  [This demo clearly shows your code working fine](http://jsfiddle.net/WVbmj/) and it seems like your whole problem is caused by a duplication of `id` on the second & third `input` element.

Comment: Well the ID's are fine, just a typo here... I have fixed it! I see you example and it really works. But where do you call rules('add'), that you are mentioning. You actually on add new field to DOM and nothing else... and it works?

Comment: @PrimozRome, since your `input` fields' HTML contains the "inline" rule, you will not need to use `rules('add')`... just follow my jsFiddle and examine it carefully.

Comment: yes correct, I was reading that all in docs but unfortunately did not work for me. Yes my form is a bit more complicated, I have more rules (all inline though) and field naming is as I showed in my question. The only different thing is I use jQuery to clone existing fieldset, and in run-time change field names and ID's... Maybe this brakes something on the way, but resulting form field names and IDs are definitely fine! I will try and re-check everything for 10th time :).

Comment: @PrimozRome, typically, using inline rules is the easiest way to apply the validation to dynamic fields.  Can you construct a simple and concise version of your code in a jsFiddle?  Then I may see what you might be doing wrong instead of guessing.

Comment: @PrimozRome dont worry about that, i got the same problem. i believe its a bug in the validation plugin. i also have a complicated form with cloning/removing inputs and sometimes the error message shows at a wrong input, but nevertheless it validates actually correctly, just the message is shown somewhere else

Comment: @ulkas, no idea what you're doing wrong. My complex dynamic forms have never had an issue with error placement.

Comment: @Sparky i build a fiddle, but it is missing plenty of data since i can't publish the company internals, but you can try to play with this form - combine all the inputs with all the buttons, put some data into the forms (especially those with `*`), move up/down, than remove those data, copy etc and you might hit the behavior described above. http://jsfiddle.net/2puj6/

Answer (score 0):

In order to validate dynamic fields we need to add class to dynamic control and append rule to it

and we need to repeat this for every append operation..

```
<input id="Name" name="Name" type="text" class="netEmp form-control">
```

for more information click here http://www.dotnetqueries.com/Article/136/jquery-validate-dynamically-added-fields

Answer (score 0):

You should set class name same for all field.

For example:

```
<input class="form-control amount validate_form" name="amount[]" type="text">
<p class="validateError" style="color:red;display:none;">please enter amount.</p>
<button type="submit" id="fees_stream_submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).on('click', '#fees_stream_submit', function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
                $(".validate_form").each(function() {
                    var selectedTr = $(this);
                    i =0;
                    var value = $(this).val();
                    if (!value) {
                        selectedTr.next("p").show();
                        i++;
                    } else {
                        selectedTr.next("p").hide();
                    }
                });

                if (i == 0) {
                    $('#fees_stream_form').submit();
                }
            });
        </script>
```